# How to get `Type.GenericParameterPosition` for method parameter of class-generic type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

It's easy to get the `GenericParameterPosition` for a parameter when its type is a generic type argument of the method:

```cs
public class MyClass {
    public void Foo<T>(T a) { }
}

// ...

Console.WriteLine("pos: " + typeof(MyClass)
    .GetMethod("Foo")
    .GetParameters()
    .Single()
    .ParameterType
    .GenericParameterPosition);
```

> pos: 0

But how can we accomplish this for a parameter who's type is a generic type argument of the *class*?

```cs
public class MyClass<T> {
    public void Foo(T a) { }
}

// ...

Console.WriteLine("pos: " + typeof(MyClass<int>)
    .GetMethod("Foo")
    .GetParameters()
    .Single()
    .ParameterType
    .GenericParameterPosition);
```

> InvalidOperationException: Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyClass<int>` is a *constructed type*, so as far as the runtime is concerned, the parameter of `Foo` *is* `int`, not a generic parameter. Compare this to the generic method `Foo<T>`, where the runtime doesn't know what type `T` is, and it only knows it's the generic parameter.

Therefore, you should use an open type such as `MyClass<>`:

```
Console.WriteLine("pos: " + typeof(MyClass<>)
    .GetMethod("Foo")
    .GetParameters()
    .Single()
    .ParameterType
    .GenericParameterPosition);
```

This way, `Foo`'s parameter type is recognised as a generic parameter.

You can also use `GetGenericTypeDefnition` to change a constructed type to an open type:

```
Console.WriteLine("pos: " + typeof(MyClass<int>)
    .GetGenericTypeDefinition()
    ...
```

This is useful if the `Type` object comes from somewhere you have no control over.

Comment: Nice! `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` is what I needed.